# How long is Stripe receipt url valid for?

Tags: stripe-payments

Can't seems to find this in the Stripe Docs, but anyone know how long the [receipt url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_url) is valid for? And also the `download invoice` and `download receipt` links in the receipt url?

Comment: Are you sure you mean the receipt and not the invoice, it would make sense the receipt is valid forever since it can be seen as proof of payment (or refund). Invoices are however valid for 60 days max. https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/hosted-invoice-page

Comment: @geertjanknapen, yes, I mean the receipt url and not the [hosted invoice page](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/hosted-invoice-page). It makes sense to me too that receipt url should be valid forever, but when it comes to $$$ and compliances matters, I need to make sure it's stated somewhere

Comment: I just went through all the docs and I am also unable to find anything regarding how long receipts are valid for. Maybe you can contact Stripe support @ https://support.stripe.com/contact/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the Stripe docs:

> As a security measure, receipt links expire within 30 days. Accessing an expired receipt link resends the receipt to the original recipient.

Although I'm not sure if the resending also refreshes the viewable receipt at the URL.

https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

Comment: Based on Stripe's updated doc, technically, I think the original receipt will remains forever. After 30 days, a new link will be sent to the recipient that points to the original receipt